# ZLIB inflate stream header format

Tags: header, zlib, inflate, bitstream

after downloading ZLIB ver. 1.2.11 and looking through RFC1951
I'm trying to use ZLIB.inflate function like this:

```
#include "zlib.h"

int iRslt;
unsigned char buffIn[4]={0x4b,4,0,0};
unsigned char buffOut[16];
z_stream zStrm;

  memset(&zStrm, 0, sizeof(zStrm));
  zStrm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
  zStrm.zfree = Z_NULL;
  zStrm.opaque = Z_NULL;
  zStrm.avail_in = 0;
  zStrm.next_in = Z_NULL;
  iRslt = inflateInit(&zStrm);
  if(iRslt != Z_OK) return;

  zStrm.avail_in = sizeof(buffIn);
  zStrm.next_in = buffIn;
  zStrm.avail_out = sizeof(buffOut);
  zStrm.next_out = buffOut;
  iRslt = inflate(&zStrm, Z_NO_FLUSH);
  if(iRslt == Z_DATA_ERROR){//-3
    //why do I end up here with zStrm.msg -> "incorrect header check"?
  }
```

My buffIn contains bitstream header 011b: BFINAL=1; BTYPE=01b; and fixed Huffman code for character 'a' (0x61) followed by at least 7 zero bits to end the block. Evidently that's not enough; please help.
Many thanks in advance;
Boba.

Comment: You do not need the `memset()`.

Comment: You have an extraneous zero in your input. That raw deflate stream is three bytes.

Comment: it's a habit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is looking for a zlib stream header, as defined in RFC 1950. It's not finding it. That RFC defines the zlib header and trailer that is wrapped around a raw deflate stream.

You have a raw deflate stream in your question. To decode that instead of a zlib stream, you would need to use `inflateInit2()` with a `windowBits` value of `-15`.

Comment: many thanks, Mark. I'm reading the 1950 and will test after the game.

Comment: Mark, you are the solver; thank you for the fast and accurate answer.